# Why there is no EntityManager.persist which takes a collection?

Tags: jpa

I know its implementation may be a simple for loop but why there is no EntityManager.persist method which takes a collection and persist all of the entities in the collection?

Comment: Obviously such a method would allow a JPA implementation to do bulk persists potentially more efficiently ... which is why JDO has had that method since 2002

Answer (score 3):

One reason is that it would be hard to know which of the entities would be the cause of the exception potentially thrown by persist(). Another reason is that there is no need to clutter the API with shortcut methods that could be trivially implemented by the user of the API.

Answer (score 2):

I agree JPA should define one.  Please email the JPA spec committee to request it.
merge/remove/etc should also take a collection.

Actually, there is nothing preventing the provider from accepting a collection as the methods take Object, perhaps request your provider allow a collection.